# jquery redirect to another page anchor on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

In jQuery, I am trying to redirect to an anchor point of a new page on ajax success.

This is how I tried it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.user-log', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var logID = $(this).data('log-id'); 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/update_log_status.inc.php',
    data: {'logID': logID}, 
    success: function(json) {
      json = jQuery.parseJSON(json);          
      if (json.success) {
        $(window).attr('location','view-log#row_11');

        window.jQuery("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: $('#row_11').offset().top - 100
        }, 500);   
        
      }
    } 
  })
});
```

In my code, redirect is working, but I am getting a console error.

That error message as follows:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).offset() is undefined

This error is saying about this line;

```
scrollTop: $('#row_11').offset().top - 100
```

This redirect page have a jquery datatable and this `#row_11` anchor is a row of that table.

Can you tell me what would be the reason for this issue?

Comment: I would suspect that the page hasn't fully loaded when the $('#row_11') fires, could you pass a query to the new page something a bit like  "mypage.html?ref=row_11" then on that page have a page on load jquery function read that in and run the scroll to function from within the page load.

Comment: @PatrickHume My new page url `view-log#row_11` is equal to `view-log.php#row_11`